# How do you configure a per-environment appsettings.json config in a Blazor client application?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-client-side, .net-5

I have a client app in blazor that connects to a server. When I'm running it on my local machine in dev, the server's hostname is dev.someurl.com

When it's live it's live.someurl.com

I've set up injection of `IConfiguration` which loads appsettings.Development.json automatically, however I can't change the environment. The docs say that when published it will use appsettings.Production.json however this is not the case as I've published it under Release build and seen that.

The environment appears to be readonly. With a signalr .net core app I can do this:

`return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseEnvironment(environmentName)`

However with a blazor client application you have this:

`var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);`

The builder lets you access `HostEnvironment` but you cannot modify it.

The reading of the appsettings config file is all automatic, built in with this code:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton(provider =>
{
    var config = provider.GetService<IConfiguration>();
    return config;
});
```

Any ideas how I can get around this?

Being a blazor client app you can apparently set the environment in a header, but I can't figure out how to do that programatically. Ideas welcome.

Comment: The environment name is defined by the *Blazor-Environment* response header of /_framework/blazor.boot.json request.

Comment: Apparently you can put it into `index.html` as `<head><meta http-equiv="Blazor-Environment" content="Staging" /></head>` but it's unclear how you make this dynamic.

Comment: if you put it in index.html it's not dynamic. Else, it's the .net server environment

Comment: dynamic as in, when I build the project I want it to be set according to my configuration e.g. debug/release so that I can easily publish it and have it use a different config

Comment: That doesn't work like this, the environment is defined by the host. And IMO, it's not a good practice to define the running environment at build time. You should deploy a release version to your Staging, UAT and/or Production

Comment: There is no host, it's a blazor client app. Yes, that's what I want to do. I want to publish a release version to the server. And I want it to use the release config. But I cannot figure out how to set it, which is the whole reason for this. I can manually edit the index.html to set that `http-equiv` to production before I click publish but that would be hacky and I'd have to do it every time

Comment: you deploy to static page server like github page or you use a web server you can manage ?